# Python: count how many lines have specific words

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently writing an script which is counting two specific words line by line in a file.
But when running my script the end count is everytime zero even if both of the words exist in the line.

This is my code:

```
file = open('sample.txt','r')

word1 = 'cookies'
word2 = 'waffles'
combined = word1 and word2

count = 0
for line in file.read():
    if combined in line:
        count = count+1
print(count)
```

The content of the file:

```
I love cookies and waffles
I love cookies and waffles
```

What I expect the output to be:
`2`

What the output actually is:
`0`

I would be really glad if someone could explain to me how I can get my script running properly:)

Thank's for every help and suggestion in advance:)

Comment: Hint: `combined = word1 and word2` is not doing what you think it is doing

Comment: @Wondercricket o ok. What is it doing:)?

Comment: What do *you* think it is doing, and why do you think that?

Comment: Step through your code and find out. [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) We expect you to do basic diagnosis of the problem before asking. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is `file.read()` return individual characters so if print it you will understand so to deal with this problem we are using `file.readlines()` so the below code works absolutely fine

```
count=0
lines=file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    if any(word in line for word in words):
        count+=1 
print(count)
```

Comment: thank you very very much for your help and time @Owais_Raxa:)

Comment: Just a heads up that you might want `all()` rather than `any()` if you require both words to exist in order to count the line rather than either of them.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do this. If you want both words in the line use `all` instead of `any`.

```
words = ["cookies", "waffles"]
count=0
for line in file.read():
    if any(word in line for word in words):
        count+=1 
print(count)
```